# Regexp pattern - is it correct and what is its purpose?

Tags: linux, bash, regular-expression

Is this pattern correct?

```
logPattern = ^NAME.log(-\d+)?$
```

What is the purpose of this?

Answer (score 1):

Quoting directly from [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/kB7qW9/1) - a great page for testing and explaining regular expressions:

```
/^NAME.log(-\d+)?$/
```

- `^` assert position at start of the string
- `NAME` matches the characters NAME literally (case sensitive)
- `.` matches any character (except newline)
- `log` matches the characters log literally (case sensitive)

Capturing group `(-\d+)?`

- Quantifier: `?` Between zero and one time, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]
- `-` matches the character - literally
- `\d` match a digit [0-9]
- Quantifier: `+` Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]
- `$` assert position at end of the string

So basically, this searches for strings (particularly file names I suppose) matching the pattern `NAME.log` or `NAME.log-123456789` (no limit on number of digits).

Most probably it should be changed to match literal dot instead of "any character", so a backslash (`\`) should be added before the dot in the expression.

Comment: @JoséLuis - welcome to StackOverflow. As a general rule, please do not post answers like 'Thank you', but accept the answer instead. You can read more about it here: http://unix.stackexchange.com/tour